# Can a vector $v$ and $2v$ be constructed out of attached regular tetrahedrons?

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Given a regular tetrahedron with its vertices $A,B,C,D$.

An attached tetrahedron can be constructed by a reflection of one point at the plane defined by the other 3 points.

For regular tetrahedron this can be simplified (as far as I know) to:
$$A' = (B+C+D)\cdot2/3-A$$
(this will result in a regular tetrahedron attached to the BCD plane)

---

If we repeat this multiple times we can produce some 'straight' progression through space.
E.g. with given start $A_0,B_0,C_0,D_0$:
1.) Compute $A'$ 
2.) Set new tetrahedron to $A_{i+1}= B_i, B_{i+1}= C_i, C_{i+1}= D_i, D_{i+1}= A'$ 
3.) Go to 1.)

We will get something like this: 
[image]

---

**Question:**
Ist there any tetrahedron $A_k,B_k,C_k,D_k$ constructed that way with:
$$A_k-A_0 = A_{2k}-A_k = \vec{v}$$
$$B_k-B_0 = B_{2k}-B_k = \vec{v}$$
$$C_k-C_0 = C_{2k}-C_k = \vec{v}$$
$$D_k-D_0 = D_{2k}-D_k = \vec{v}$$
And with this:
$$A_{2k}-A_0 = 2\vec{v}$$
$$A_{n+k}-A_n = \vec{v} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } \forall n$$
So the $(2k)$'th tetrahedron would be the $0$'th shifted by vector $2 \vec{v}$. And the $(n+k)$'th tetrahedron would be the $n$'th shifted by vector $\vec{v}$.

---

In tests (up to $k=1000$) the $k=254$ is very close to but not equal. 
Is there any $k$ which does work out?

Or if not is there any other kind of attachment order which can produce such a vector ($\ne\vec{0}$, (plane attached to plane) )?

---

Edit: Thanks to Intelligenti pauca this is similar problem as for the [Boerdijk–Coxeter Helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boerdijk%E2%80%93Coxeter_helix)

with vertices coordinates:
$$ (r \cos n\theta ,r\sin n\theta ,nh) $$
with:
$$r=3\sqrt{3}/10, \theta=\pm\cos^{-1}(-2/3) \approx 131.81^\circ, h=1/\sqrt{10}$$
The problem is equal with finding integer $n_1$, $n_2$ with:
$$\cos(n_1 \theta) = \cos(n_2 \theta)$$
$$\sin(n_1 \theta) = \sin(n_2 \theta)$$

Comment: See if this can be of help: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.00280

Comment: Your polyhedron should be a [Boerdijk–Coxeter Helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boerdijk–Coxeter_helix).

Comment: @Intelligentipauca thank you for those interesting links. Haven't read all yet but as far I understood it can be very close but for regular tetrahedron there is no solution known yet and probably won't exist. If I use the coordinates given for Boerdijk–Coxeter Helix (at wiki) I also get the result of 254 but somehow it does not match up with the apparent twist 23.62°.